# Axios.delete(url[,config]): Type has no properties in common with type 'AxiosRequestConfig'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, eslint, typescript-eslint

I use React, Typescript and Axios. I declare a class to be populated by static functions like this :

```
import axios from "axios"

export default class Users {

  static checkinByPassword(username: string, password: string){
    const params = {username, password}
    return axios.post(`/${this._key}/checkinbypassword`, params)
  }

  static delete(id: string){
    const params = {id: id}
    return axios.delete(`/${this._key}`, params)
  }
}
```

The first function (checkinByPassword) works fine. The second function make ESLint (I use ESLint for VSCode Editor) throwing an error :

```
Type '{ id: string; }' has no properties in common with type 'AxiosRequestConfig'.
```

[image: screenshot in VSCode]

What's `AxiosRequestConfig` ? and how do I make my params object to be compatible with it?
Thank you in  advance

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`axios.delete` takes two argument, first is a url path and second is config.

You need to wrap your params object another object which has a `data` property.

**For example:**

```
const config = {
  data: {
    id: "your id"
  }
}

axios.delete(url, config)...
```

or

```
const params = {id: id};

axios.delete(url, {
  data: params
})...
```

Comment: well... it's work! But here: https://github.com/axios/axios#note they said that `When using the alias methods url, method, and data properties don't need to be specified in config`. As far as I know, the .delete() method is one of the alias

Comment: Mm.. Yes. Maybe you are right or the author wanted to say something else..

BTW i suggest you continue coding.